# Frustum culling issue at oblique angles

Tags: c++, 3d, mathematics, frustum-culling

I am using the following algorithm to test if my camera frustum contains an axis-aligned bounding box:

```
float plane_dot(XMVECTOR plane, XMVECTOR point)
{
    return XMVectorGetX(XMVector3Dot(plane, point)) + XMVectorGetW(plane);
}

bool is_box_visible(XMVECTOR planes[6], XMVECTOR center, XMVECTOR extents)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        XMVECTOR plane = planes[i];
        float aabb_radius = fabs(XMVectorGetX(plane) * XMVectorGetX(extents)) 
                          + fabs(XMVectorGetY(plane) * XMVectorGetY(extents)) 
                          + fabs(XMVectorGetZ(plane) * XMVectorGetZ(extents));
        to_center = plane_dot(plane, center);
        if (to_center <= -aabb_radius)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage code:

```
    XMMATRIX to_view = XMLoadFloat4x4(&debug_cam->m_view);
    XMVECTOR center = XMVectorSet(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f);
    XMVECTOR extents = XMVectorSet(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.f);

    center = XMVector4Transform(center, to_view);
    extents = XMVector4Transform(extents, to_view);

    XMVECTOR vs_far_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_far_plane), to_view);
    XMVECTOR vs_near_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_near_plane), to_view);
    XMVECTOR vs_top_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_top_plane), to_view);
    XMVECTOR vs_bottom_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_bottom_plane), to_view);
    XMVECTOR vs_left_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_left_plane), to_view);
    XMVECTOR vs_right_plane = XMVector4Transform(XMLoadFloat4(&debug_cam->m_right_plane), to_view);

    XMVECTOR planes[6] = {vs_left_plane, vs_right_plane, vs_bottom_plane, vs_top_plane, vs_far_plane, vs_near_plane};

    extents = XMVectorAbs(extents);
    center = XMVectorAbs(center);

    is_visible = is_box_visible(planes, center, extents);
```

It works correctly in most situations, as can be seen here (notice the `is_visible` checkbox is correctly checked):
[image]

But when looking from certain angles the function returns incorrect results:
[image]

Is this a limitation of this particular algorithm or is there a bug in my code?

Comment: Think the best way here is to generate the 8 points that represent your box and test that any of lay within frustum.  As you have 6 planes that represent the frustum, you can do a Vector4 dot  test against the 8 points to see that they are in front of the plane(s).  I've not seen the test you have implemented before, that's not to say the algorthm is wrong, just that I can't validate the implementations accuracy.

Comment: `float to_center = dot(plane.xyz, half_extents) + plane.w;` This does not look geometrically meaningful. It looks like you're trying to compute the distance from the plane to the center of the AABB, but that should not use the half extents here. Your code never actually uses the `aabb_center` value, which means it completely ignores the position of the box relative to the frustum. That's a big red flag. It also looks strange to me that you're converting your planes to view space, but not your object position?

Comment: @DMGregory You're right, I made a mistake when writing the code for this post. I use `aabb_center` instead of `half_extents` to get the `to_center` value. I also forgot to convert the object positions to view space.  I updated the original post.

Comment: The code you've posted will always return false. Are you sure you've posted the actual code you're using?

Comment: @MaximusMinimus I just corrected that also... I had to translate the math code from DirectXMath to something more readable but I made like 4 mistakes in the process. I think I fixed all the mistakes now.

Comment: It still always returns false. It might be better if you just pasted the original DirectXMath code you actually use.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus Yeah it was a bad idea. I just replaced the pseudocode with exactly what I'm using.